# Best method to add/remove webcontrols or user controls in asp.net dynamic forms without postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Best method to add/remove webcontrols or user controls in asp.net for dynamic forms without postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ASP.NET Ajax, although technically this is a postback, yet it doesn't (really) feel like one for the end-user.

If that is also not allowed, you can just add html elements using javascript.